# How to Access Different Facebook Accounts Through My iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook

This is the first time I have integrated facebook into an app so I am sure I must have missed something. The problem I'm having is that I can only access my OWN facebook account through my iOS app with facebook integration.

The specifics:
I integrated facebook (SDK 3.1) into my app (xcode 4.5) successfully. The very first time I logged into facebook through my app it asked for my password, etc. Works fine on the simulator and my iPhone (iOS 6) to access my friends and their info, BUT here are the two problems:

1) When I click the "facebook logout" button that I set up, and then I log back in, it says I am "already authorized" to use the app. There is no option to change the facebook user.

2) I sent the app to a friend through testflight and when he opens it on his phone and clicks log in to Facebook with his own account, he gets an error that reads "com.facebooksdk error 2."

Why can't I change the facebook user who is using the app? I followed the tutorial called "Login" on the Fb app developer website to set this up: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

I also used some code from the "Run SQL Queries" tutorial to grab my friends photos: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/

Can any help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I posted this question a while back, but in case it is helpful to anyone - I believe I was in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your friend as a developer to the app (in the 'Roles' part of the app dashboard for your app).

If you want to deauthorize the app, go the desktop version of Facebook, and in the account settings (under 'Apps'), delete the app in question. You'll be asked to reauthorize when you run the app up again.

You might also find this sample in the SDK useful: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SwitchUserSample

Comment: This is probably correct, but it's SO BAD. Android Facebook apps don't behave like this. Here's how my (Android) app behaves: If I'm not already logged into a Facebook account on the device, then I'm prompted for the account and password. This happens EVERY time after I log out from my app. If I am logged into Facebook at the time I log into the app, then yeah, it takes me directly to my app. This is the way iOS logins should work.